# Widgets not adding div on before and after title

Tags: widgets, title

I'm trying to get a wrapper around my h3 widget title, because i want to give the h3 a vertical align bottom. Currently i'm registering my widget as following:

```
function usp_widgets_init(){
    if (function_exists('register_sidebar')) {
        register_sidebar(array(
            'name' => 'Front page widgets',
            'id' => 'widgets-front',
            'description' => 'Geschikt voor de USPs',
            'before_widget' => '<div class="skill hidden">',
            'after_widget' => '</div>',
            'before_title' => '<div class="widget-title"><h3>',
            'after_title' => '</h3></div>'
        ));
    }
} add_action( 'widgets_init', 'usp_widgets_init' );
```

Now the title will get the h3 tags, but it isn't wrapped by the div. Does anyone know how to fix this? Btw, i can't use display:table-cell for vertical aligning.

Current output:

```
<h3>Widget Title</h3>
```

Wished output:

```
<div class='widget-title'><h3>Widget Title</h3></div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I see I accidentally added an extra quote (") after widget-title, but this happened with copy-pasting. This is not in my source code so it's not the problem.

Comment: Are you looking at the raw source of your page or an inspector view?  What happens if you remove your `if` statement?

Comment: Your code looks fine to me, except that the conditional is not necessary. Might be some sort of caching problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed *,* at the of after_title that's why it's not working. Use this code it's working fine.

```
register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => 'Custom code widget',
        'id'            => 'custom-code',
        'description'   => 'Cutom code for all pages.',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="custom-description">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<div class="custom-code-title"><h2 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2></div>',
    ) );
```